# Install Windows 10 SDK 10.0.18362 on Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017

i'm currently trying to install Windows SDK 10.0.18362 on Visual Studio Community 2017.

I first tried to simply use the visual installer but i can't see the 10.0.18362 Version the newest i have is the SDK Windows 10 (10.0.17763.0).

I also tried to use the installer from https://developer.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk. But when the download finishes and i get the message "Please find winsdksetup.exe in ...\windowsSDK ...". I try to run the .exe and it loops on the download application from earlier.

Can you help me please ?

EDIT : Tried to use the .ISO file from Microsoft to install the SDK and got the same loop. Making update with Windows Update did not change anything.

Just find out that i did not have the latest Insider Update installed and for some reason i was still on Windows 10.0.17763.0

Comment: I can confirm, the correct file can be [downloaded](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), and the installer is for `Windows SDK 10.0.18362`

Comment: Did you download and try with the ISO file?

Comment: @Biswapriyo It did exactly the same thing as the first installer. But i'm installing some update with Windows Update to make sure it is not coming from there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - I figured out it's because the installer is poorly coded.

The fix to this problem is to simply uninstall the Windows SDK already present on your machine.