# WinDbg repeatedly downloads but doesn't install

Tags: installation, windbg

I'm trying to install WinDbg from Microsoft's [Hardware Dev Centre](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/) but at the end of the download process it tells me to run the installer again which merely downloads the same files again:

[image]

How do you actually install WinDbg?

Comment: Have you ran the specified file?   Based on error message it appears your running the incorrect file.

Comment: I'm running `D:\downloads\Windows Kits\10\WindowsSDK\winsdksetup.exe`. As far as I can tell it's exactly what the dialog box is asking me to run. I don't see any similarly named files in the same folder. The only other file is `UserExperienceManifest.xml`, and there is also a folder `Installers`.

Comment: What is in the installers folder?

Comment: @Moab A whole bunch of `.msi` files. Far more than I asked to download.

Comment: You should install any version of the Windows SDK you currently have installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Windows 10 SDK 10.0.18362 on Visual Studio Community 2017](https://superuser.com/questions/1437324/install-windows-10-sdk-10-0-18362-on-visual-studio-community-2017)

Comment: @Ramhound That is exactly my problem. But I don't see any version of the SDK installed. How would I find it?

Comment: It would be in Add/Remove Programs.  It's listed under "Windows Software Development Kit"

Comment: There is a Windows SDK **Addon** in Control Panel > "Apps & features". Is it installed as an add-on of Visual Studio?

Comment: OK, I've found two of them, both installed on 24/09/2019! `10.0.17763.132` and `10.0.18362.1`.

Comment: @CJDennis - Uninstall the version you are attempting to install, then reinstall that version, the error is due to the fact your trying to install it instead of modify the current install.

Answer (score 1):

The reason WinDbg won't install is because it's detected that the Windows Software Development Kit is already installed. In that case, it's not necessary to reinstall it, you can just change its features.

Go to "Apps & features" (in Windows Settings) search for "Windows Software Development Kit", select it and press "Modify". Leave "Change" selected and press "Next". You can then tick "Debugging Tools for Windows" (if it's not already ticked) and press "Change".

Answer (score 0):

> How do you actually install WinDbg?

You currently already have the `Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.18362.1` installed, and this error is caused by trying to install a new instance, instead of modifying the current installation.

The simple workaround is to uninstall it and reinstall it and select the required `Debugging Tools` for Windows`option.  You could also modify the current installation if you want, by selecting the installation within Add/Remove Programs, and selecting **Change** and adding the`Debugging Tools`

[image]

Comment: Great! Now that I've done that (uninstalled and reinstalled) I see that you can just modify the existing installation (no need to go to Microsoft and download extra stuff). Now I have no idea what feature were installed previously.

Comment: @CJDennis - Whatever feature you originally installed.  Since you have multiple versions installed.  You can base your decision on which features you need based on what features you have installed.

Comment: I never installed it in the first place. I've never heard of it before today. Since I uninstalled it I had no features installed.

Comment: @CJDennis - You have Visual Studio installed, you had 2 different versions installed, you might not have been aware you installed it but you did install it.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. You did solve my problem but not without doing unintended changes.